# Sort timestamps into differents arrays from xlsx file

Tags: python, arrays, excel

[xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eu5v.png)

(Using python)

In the column :'klokkeslett', i want to transfer the time from 08:00:00 to 10:00:00 to an array. And from 10:00:00 to 12:00:00  in to another array and so on.

How can i do that using python(Jupiter notebook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Jupiter creates a list (going to use the python term for array) of dictionaries containing your data, try something like this:

```
# Assume data_set is the information that you get from Jupiter in list of dictionaries format.
# Also assuming the contents of klokkeslett are in datetime.time format; adjust for what it uses.
data_8_10 = [x for x in data_set if datetime.time(8, 0, 0) <= x['klokkeslett'] < datetime.time(10, 0, 0)]
data_10_12 = [x for x in data_set if datetime.time(10, 0, 0) <= x['klokkeslett'] < datetime.time(12, 0, 0)]
```

Basically the idea is that you'll create a new list from the contents of the old list.